# React-Native - undefined is not an object" (evaluating 'this.state.*) _renderRow

Tags: reactjs, state, react-native

I am trying to call the state inside the _renderRow() function but I keep receiving the following error:

[image]

This is my source code:
**Source code**

```
 var Store = require('./store/Store.js');
 var MessageOptions = require('./MessageOptions.js')

 var React = require('react');
 var ReactNative = require('react-native');
 var {
   AppRegistry,
   Image,
   ListView,
   StyleSheet,
   Text,
   View,
 } = ReactNative;


var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2})

 class Application extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {

   super(props);

   this.state = {
      selectedRowID: 20,
      dataSource: ds
   }
}


componentWillMount() {

  this.getNewMessages();
}


getNewMessages() {

   Store.getMessages().then((messages) => {

       this.setState({
         dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(messages)
       });

   },(reason) => {

       console.log("Error:", reason);
   });
}


_renderRow(rowData: string, sectionID: number, rowID: number, highlightRow: (sectionID: number, rowID: number) => void) {

  var currentSelectedRowID = this.state.selectedRowID;
  return (

        <View>
           <View style={styles.row}>
              <Image style={styles.thumb} source={require('../android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher.png')} />
              <Text style={styles.text}>
                 {rowData.text}
              </Text>
           </View>
           <MessageOptions optionsData={rowData.options} message_uri={rowData.uri}/>
        </View>

   )
}


render() {
  return (
     <ListView
       dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
       renderRow={this._renderRow}
     />
  )
}
};


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  thumb: {
    width: 64,
    height: 64,
  },
  text: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  news_item: {
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    marginBottom: 5
  },
   news_item_text: {
    color: '#575757',
    fontSize: 18
  }
});


module.exports = Application;
```

The error is coming from the _renderRow method where I am storing this.state.selectedRowID to the var currentSelectedRowID.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in _renderRow and use your react dev tools to see what the state looks like and what you have access too. My guess is that how it's being called, makes the state out of scope. You can also try {this._renderRow.bind(this)}

Comment: I just added "this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this);" to the constructor but no luck. I have to look into the debugging. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I implemented  "this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this);" incorrectly. You were correct.

Comment: bind it properly `renderRow = {()=>_renderRow}` or something like that can't remember the syntax, this way you don't have to bind it in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**
The problem was with my ES6 class constructor:

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {

   super(props);
   this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this);

   this.state = {
      selectedRowID: 20,
      dataSource: ds
   }
}
```

The solution was to add the following line to my constructor:

```
this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this);
```